# Converting maps from Firestore to dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a order system, and for that, I am storing the cart of a user in Firestore with maps, so the collection will be called "carts", then the document will be saved as the user's UID and inside of the document there should be maps with what he ordered, the quantity and the price of those things, so for example he orders 4 things and for that there are 4 maps in which there are the item names, the quantity and the price stored.

Now I don't know how I can retrieve this data from Firebase within Swift and save it in a dictionary. For other data types I always used a SnapshotListener, but I really have no idea how that would work for data in maps that I want to save in dictionaries.

Edit:
My firebase structure would be like this and I want to save this data (item name, quantity, price) in one dictionary in Swift, so that I can pass on this information as one.

[image: My database structure in Firestore]

Edit 2:

```
class readDrinksFromDb: ObservableObject {
@Published var items = [Item]()
@ObservedObject var userInfo = UserData()

init () {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let itemsRef = db.collection("drinks")
    let loungeRef = itemsRef.document(userInfo.user.reserviert) // Should get the lounge Name -> XYZ Lounge

    loungeRef.getDocument { (snap, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let snap = snap else { return }
        guard let dict = snap.data() else { return }

        dict.forEach { i in
            let orderItems = dict[i.key] as! [String: String]
            let id = orderItems["id"] ?? ""
            let price = orderItems["price"] ?? ""
            let pic = orderItems["pic"] ?? ""
            let name = orderItems["name"] ?? ""

            self.items.append(Item(id: id, name: name, price: price, pic: pic, lounge: "Rebell Lounge", type: "drinks"))
        }

        print(self.items)
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Describing the issue is a good start but we really need to see your firebase structure as well as what code you've attempted. It's a bit unclear what the actual issue is - reading data from Firestore is covered in the getting started guide so that's a good point of reference.

Comment: @Jay edited my firebase structure in, hope this helps. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may not fully understand the question but I think you're asking how to read data from a document in Firestore and access the child data.

I'm including two examples, one using dictionaries to get to the data and the second using .map. Read through the first part first as it best illustrates the relationships between the data

**Dictionaries:**

If so, assuming the users uid is 'user_0', we'll read the topmost document has the users uid as the documentId.

Once we have the document, we use the .data property to get all of the data as a Dictionary.

```
guard let dict = snap.data() else { return }
```

Then, the field (a dictionary key) we are interested in is called 'drinks' so we use the 'drinks' key to get it's value (which is another dictionary)

```
let orderItems = dict["drinks"] as! [String: String]
```

The overall structure looks like this

```
["drinks": {
    item = fanta;
    price = "4.50";
    quantity = 2;
}]
```

As you can see drinks is the key and then the item, price and quantity are the value associated with that key

Then, those items are cast to a orderItems variable

```
let orderItems = dict["drinks"] as! [String: String]
```

which is also a dictionary and contains the keys and values of the data you want

```
func readOrder() {
    let orderRef = self.db.collection("orders") //self.db = my Firestore
    let thisUser = orderRef.document("user_0")

    thisUser.getDocument(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let snap = snapshot else { return }

        guard let dict = snap.data() else { return }

        let orderItems = dict["drinks"] as! [String: String]

        let item = orderItems["item"] ?? "No Item"
        let price = orderItems["price"] ?? "No Price"
        let qty = orderItems["quantity"] ?? "No Quantity"
        print(item, price, qty)
    })
}
```

**Using .map**

```
func readOrder() {
    let orderRef = self.db.collection("orders")
    let thisUser = orderRef.document("user_0")

    thisUser.getDocument(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let mappedField = snapshot.map {$0}
        let orderDict = mappedField?.get("drinks") as! [String: String]
        let item = orderDict["item"] ?? "No Item"
        let created = orderDict["price"] ?? "No Price"
        let age = orderDict["quantity"] ?? "No qty"
        print(item, created, age)
    })
}
```

**Edit**

Responding to a comment about how to iterate over a dictionary to get it's  key: value pairs. Here's two options

```
for (key, value) in dict {
    print(key, value)
}

dict.forEach { key, value in
    print(key, value)
}
```

Comment: one more question, you use "let orderDict = mappedField?.get("drinks") as! [String: String], how would I iterate through every map in said document ("user_0") without knowing their names? Tried a ForEach loop, an index loop, and so on but all of them do not quite work the way I want them to work. Basically if there are the different dictionaries which I do not the keys of, but I want to retrieve all of them. How exactly would I do that? Would really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: @sk.42 Are you asking how to iterate over each key: value pair in a dictionary? I updated my answer with an Edit to show two options.

Comment: I have just one more question, it is something I don't really understand how to fix but I don't want to open a new thread for that. To get to my document, I have to provide a collection (drinks) and a document name (user_0 for example), now to get that document name I have to call my class UserData() which collects all the user's data. I have edited in my class in the question above. Now the problem is that I can't access that UserData() information in my init() function. How do I fix this problem? Because otherwise I won't be able to get my user's data for the document name of the order.

Comment: @sk.42 Not sure I understand the question.... typically, a certain users data is stored in a document with their uid being the documentId. Then, once the user authenticates, you can retrieve their uid from the Auth().current user object, then you'll know the path to their data. Now... you're saying *can't access that UserData() information in my init() function* - why not? What's stopping you from doing that? If  there's more to it, probably best open another question so we don't take this one off topic

Comment: I opened another thread about my problem, maybe you could give it a look as well if you understand my problem. Much appreciated :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012986/use-firebase-class-in-init-of-other-class